# Ubuntu clear Apache2 error log

Tags: permissions, apache2, error-handling

I am new to Ubuntu. I can find my error log here in `var/log/apache2/error.log`. but i couldn't clear it. i tried to change the permission to edit the content. But couldn't achieve it.

Please help me to remove it. I have read some question previously asked. but it does-not help me .

this one I read https://askubuntu.com/questions/574725/how-to-clear-system-logs-in-ubuntu.

Here is my terminal screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most files in `/var/log` are owned by root.

So, if you want to modify them, you will have to use `sudo`.

To clear the error file, give command:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo > /var/log/apache2/error.log'
```

If that doesn't work, then very likely the `apache` process keeps the file locked and you have to stop apache before you can clear the file. This goes as follows:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo bash -c 'echo > /var/log/apache2/error.log'
sudo service apache2 start
```

Note: You can't use `sudo echo > /var/log/apache2/error.log` here, because `sudo` executes the `echo` command but the redirect to `error.log` is done under the process of the user, which doesn't have elevated privileges. That's why I pass the whole command to bash, which is then executed by `sudo`.

Comment: i tried it, it prevents the permission.  I don't know how to provide access.  and here i added a screen-shot in my question by editing it

Comment: Use sudo sh -c ' echo > /path/to/file' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Comment: @Kvvaradha See my updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ sudo truncate -s 0 /path/to/log.log
```

Comment: I used this: `alias clog='sudo truncate -s 0'` then just use `clog error.log`. Nice, thanks :-D